# Runtime polyorphism and upcasting , downcasting

Tags: java

```
 class AA {  
      void run()
          {
             System.out.print("In AA");
          }  
     }  
 class B extends AA{
          void run()
         {
             System.out.print("In B");
         }  
     public static void main(String z[])
        {  

      //upcasting 
      AA a= new B();
      a.run();
    }  
}
```

Upcasting here working fine but now i m trying to call Parent class method like this..

```
B b=new AA();
```

It gives compile time error so cast it.

```
 B b=(B) new AA();
```

However, I'm not sure why it's not working how I expect. Any thoughts?

Comment: Every `B` is an `AA` but not every `AA` is `B`.

Comment: there have been thousand time the very same question was asked please do some research

Comment: you have to use instanceOf before typecasting

Comment: I am getting you guys. I know it will not work, but i am  just trying to understand the concept, So that means we can not perform downcasting here.. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a `B` class IS an instance of `AA`; however, an `AA` class IS NOT and instance of `B`

the Javac compiler has no way of knowing that there exists a class `B` that extends `AA` when you declare `new AA()`;

if you're asking behind the theory of this, the suppose you also have another class that derives `AA`, such as:

```
public class C extends AA {
    @Override void run() { System.out.println("i do something different");}
}
```

now, when you call `new AA()`, how do you know what `AA` can be casted to? what is called when you call `run()` ? is it the `run` that belongs to `B` ? or `C` ?

if it were to work polymorphically, you would need to have instantiated both a `B` and a `C` class. but wouldn't this be a total waste of space, for every children of `AA` ?

Comment: Does interface have a usage here?

Comment: @KickButtowski potentially. could you plz specify what you mean?

Answer (score 2):

What

```
B extends AA
```

mean, is that `B` is an `AA`, but `AA` is not a `B`. Let's give an example:

```
Employee extends Person
```

This means that an `Employee` is a `Person`, but a `Person` is not necesarily an `Employee`.

When you do
String literal is not properly closed by a double-quote
    AA a = new B();

the reference type of `a` will be `AA`, but the object type will be `B`. This kind of declaration only allows to call methods declared in `AA`.

Doing

```
B b = new AA();
```

won't work because an `AA` is not a `B`, as explained with the example above.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how far you have gotten with polymorphism in Java, but that is a concept you should really understand well because it is at the base of OOP.

So, using some ASCII class diagrams:

```
AA <- B
```

B is a subclass of AA. A specialized type of AA, if you want to put it in other words. So you *can* use a `AA ref = new B();`.

On the other hand, AA is not an instance of B. You cannot have a specialization of AA be used when the reference is of type B.

Let's look at an example:

```
Animal <- Cat
       <- Dog
       <- TyrannosaurusRex
```

We can all agree that Cat, Dog and TyrannosaurusRex are all animals, so you can use an `Animal a` type to point to Cat, Dog or TyrannosaurusRex. On the other hand, a `TyrannosaurusRex rex` can not be *any* animal, so it is normal that `TyrannosaurusRex rex = new Animal()` should give an error.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to study the reference variable

```
Object str =new Object() // this is Correct.
String newString = (String) str // this is not allowed because str object does not have the reference of String
```

But you are casting into String  still it not work.

```
Actually str is reference is Object.
```

Clear.

now your problem is solve

```
B has an reference of AA but 
AA  class has not reference of class B
```